# Not getting image links using REST API - images stored on S3.amazonaws through "WP Offload Media Lite” plugin

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, wordpress-rest-api

I am debugging a wordpress application which is using the
“WP Offload Media Lite” plugin to store images on amazon S3 bucket.

The “Remove Local Media” option is ON, with this plugin. So all the media are only stored on the S3 bucket.

Actually, I am not getting the image URLs from REST API (called by a mobile application).

==> **The problem does not happen on the Admin dashborad (The images are visible)**: The image urls are rendered by the “Offload Media Lite” plugin and have the form https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/10092119/blabla.png. Knowing that the project also uses the “Advanced Custom Fields PRO” and “Custom Post Type UI” plugins.

This two plugins and especially “Advanced Custom Fields PRO” works properly with “WP Offload Media Lite” and calls the right filters, to return the right urls of the image on s3.amazonaws.com.

==> **The problem happens when I use the REST API to get a post-type from the frontend** (a mobile app using wordpress as headless cms). If the post contains an image. Instead of the url of image, the API returns this block:

```
"_embedded": {
    "wp:featuredmedia": [
        {
            "code": "rest_no_route",
            "message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method.",
            "data": {
                "status": 404
            }
        }
    ],
    "wp:term": [
        …..
    ]
```

By debugging the solution, I see that the REST API try to find the images through this endpoint: “/wp/v2/media/{id}”
But for some reason, this endpoint exists only in (POST) but not in (GET) hence the error.

I don’t know if it’s abnormal that this endpoint “GET: /wp/v2/media/{id}” doesn’t exist! Or if it’s normal since the “WP Offload Media” must intercept this image search somewhere through its filters (such as the “wp_get_attachment_url” or other filters).
But I noticed none of these filters are called.

So when the REST API is called, it does not seem to communicate with the code of the “WP Offload Media Lite” plugin, which must take the id of the image, calculate and return the url to it as it does from the “Advanced Custom Fields PRO” plugin.

Do you know how to fix this, in fact I’m on a wordress project with little experience with wordpress.

What I am missing to make **WP Offload Media Lite plugin** work well with **REST API** (like it is intercepting image call and **working well when to show the image on the admin dashboard**).

THINKS